# How to get add-watch to listen to a Clojureql table

Tags: clojure

I want to be able to have add-watch to call a callback when a database table changes (via clojureql). How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an interesting idea. Right now, all table references in ClojureQL are nothing but syntax trees which do nothing before getting de-referenced. This means that what you ask isn't directly possible.

I will be happy to consider it for inclusion in a post 1.0 release, if you would please make an issue on Github.

Thanks,
Lau

Comment: Thanks Lau, but I'm not sure it belongs in ClojureQL itself, so I'm going to try and implement something like it myself.